# MagickWand: transparent SVG part rendered as white background

Tags: svg, imagemagick, transparent, magickwand

I am trying to read SVG images using ImageMagick (6.8.8-7) and get valid transparent pixels.

The code below is working well with PNG format, but for SVG i can only have some white background.
So i tried to add MagickSetBackgroundColor, and MagickSetImageBackgroundColor with some merging layers but i still can't make it works.

Below an extract from the PoC:

```
MagickWandGenesis();
m_wand = NewMagickWand();

MagickReadImage(m_wand, file_name);

hasAlfa = MagickGetImageAlphaChannel(m_wand);
fprintf(stderr, "alpha channel detection: %d\n", hasAlfa);

if (hasAlfa == MagickTrue) {

    PixelWand *color;
    MagickWand *new_wand;

    imagedata = malloc(w*h*4);

    color = NewPixelWand();
    PixelSetColor(color, "none");
    MagickSetBackgroundColor(m_wand, color);

    MagickSetImageBackgroundColor(m_wand, color);
    new_wand = MagickMergeImageLayers(m_wand, MergeLayer);
    DestroyMagickWand(m_wand);
    m_wand = new_wand;

    mrc = MagickExportImagePixels(m_wand, 0, 0, (size_t)w, (size_t)h, "RGBA", CharPixel, imagedata);

    fprintf(stderr, "R:%d G:%d B:%d A:%d\nR:%d G:%d B:%d A:%d\n", imagedata[0], imagedata[1], imagedata[2], imagedata[3], imagedata[4], imagedata[5], imagedata[6], imagedata[7]);
}
```

Result using a PNG image:

```
size: 9 x 11
alpha channel detection: 1
R:0 G:0 B:0 A:0
R:0 G:0 B:0 A:0
```

Result using a SVG image:

```
size: 640 x 1000
alpha channel detection: 1
R:255 G:255 B:255 A:255
R:255 G:255 B:255 A:255
```

Any clues ?

Comment: MagickSetBackgroundColor() has to be called before the MagickReadImage()

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understood your question. To convert transparence from svg to png a pixel has to be defined as transparent.
You can define transparency in svg using "opacity", but in svg transparency is only given for next layer (not alpha-layer, that shines through all objects like in alpha).
If you want alpha transparency on an png, it's really the best way to define (i.e. white), and set that to alpha transperency